# angular odd,even not working when ng-hide to split between 2 tables

Tags: angularjs, json, sorting

I have several tables with data coming from `json`.
The data is split into the two tables, based on some criteria.
This causes the index to go off, and now the angular doesn't correctly know which row is odd or even.
Thus, odd,even colors are messed up. 
Any ideas besides sorting and reindexing in the controller?
[see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zm0kxLpy/2/)

Comment: The easiest way to solve this might be to separate the data set into two separate sets, one for even categories and one for odd categories.  Otherwise, the tools which Angular offers (`ng-repeat`, `$index`, etc.) won't really help to solve the sorting problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using a filter, in your example, change:

```
ng-repeat="person in people" ng-show="person.categoryId==2"
```

to:

```
ng-repeat="person in people | filter: { categoryId: 2}"
```

Fiddle available here: http://jsfiddle.net/rm8q1gnm/

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [angular filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

Replace your code with following

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in people | filter: {categoryId:2}" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'">
```